# I am getting app bundle error while installing app on play console

Tags: java, android, upload, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

[app bundle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9zuR.png)

[android studio signing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4BNK.png)

[android studio signing 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wtz68.png)

```
I signed the application, but it says it is not signed, there is no other error, what could be the problem?
```

I tried to sign the app but when installing it says not signed I couldn't find the error any help would be appreciated

it "Android APP bundle was not signed" says